# PDF Template Archiving

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Created a form that generates a response sheet. I also have created a Doc which is a Template that my responses fill into. From here it was being turned into a PDF and e-mailed to specific recipients. I now need to archive  these into specific folders based on a columns answer. I simply first would like to just be able to move or copy them into a specific folder. How is this possible. I have used multiple scripts but just cant see where the disconnect is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you   [enter link description here](https://script.google.com/a/sealedair.com/macros/d/MasNMNy8wfwpmJKg8hY_Pdr9Vo0hcT6_t/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvHGaG7MDqQ2q-9yLN3V6Q4xSuJREfJfFaezNsbdUSUdmlprPOM7g4HfLoM_BiukN8BSNe2ovR1gRVzEr5C5G_BL4s-1P4-HMCNKBeHw9fP2GXAVp-_TpSj6O9cryGfC9jcyrDiCLaM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using some code like this:

```
function moveFileToFolder() {
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('your Folder ID');

  var theFile = DriveApp.getFileById('Your File ID').makeCopy(theFolder);

  var oldFileName = theFile.getName();

  var archivedName = oldFileName.slice(5);
  Logger.log('archivedName: ' + archivedName);

  archivedName = "archive" + archivedName;

  theFile.setName(archivedName);
}
```

To delete the old file without having to send it to the trash:

```
//This requires the Drive API To be turned on in the Advanced Google Services. 
//RESOURCES menu, ADVANCED GOOGLE SERVICES
function deleteFile(idToDLET) {
  //idToDLET = 'the File ID';

  //This deletes a file without needing to move it to the trash
  var rtrnFromDLET = Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did help. I also was unaware of the Delete File Function and this was an added bonus. Thanks